# Memory error as a result of input string processing

Tags: python-3.x

I've been getting this error while I try to run my code. If you know, how I can change it, tell me please! Two-three steps...

```
Failed test #2 of 11. Runtime error

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jailed_code", line 30, in <module>
    for j in num: 
  File "jailed_code", line 5, in aP
    a = [1]*n
MemoryError

def aP(n):
a = [1]*n
y = -1
v = n
while v > 0:
    v -= 1
    x = a[v] + 1
    while y >= 2 * x:
        a[v] = x
        y -= x
        v += 1
    w = v + 1
    while x <= y:
        a[v] = x
        a[w] = y
        yield a[:w + 1]
        x += 1
        y -= 1
    a[v] = x + y
    y = a[v] - 1
    yield a[:w]
    
lst = []
res = []
input = input().split(' ')
for i in input:
    num = aP(int(i))
    for j in num: 
        if len(j) == 3:
            lst.append(j)
    res.append(len(lst))
    lst = []
res = str(res).replace(',', '')
print(res[1:-1])
```

Comment: а что именно вы подаете на вход?

Comment: это задача с одного образовательного онлайн портала... там требовалось: "...Найдите аналитическое выражение для p3(n). Вход программы состоит из единственной строки — списка из не более чем ста тысяч чисел n i ≤2000000000, разделённых пробелом. Выведите единственную строку — список значений p3​ (ni ), разделенных пробелом, для чисел из входа....". я не прохожу там тесты по памяти, о чем упомянул в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

что именно делает ваш код?

очень похоже, что там сидит сложность O(n^3) - O(n^4), то очень нехорошо, поэтому надо знать задачу, чтобы давать какой-то совет

кстати ваш код можно слегка упростить

```
def aP(n):
    # основной код функции


res = [len([j for j in aP(i) if len(j) == 3]) for i in map(int, input().split())]
print(*res)
```

**Решение:**

Ваш код усложнен избыточно для такой задачи

Вот код который не ест память и работает на несколько порядков быстрее вашего

```
def aP(n):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, n + 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, n + 1):
            if n - i - j > j:
                count += 1
    return count


res = [aP(i) for i in map(int, input().split())]
print(*res)
```

Comment: это задача с одного образовательного онлайн портала... там требовалось: "...Найдите аналитическое выражение для p3(n). Вход программы состоит из единственной строки — списка из не более чем ста тысяч чисел n i ≤2000000000, разделённых пробелом. Выведите единственную строку — список значений p3​ (ni ), разделенных пробелом, для чисел из входа....". я не прохожу там тесты по памяти, о чем упомянул в вопросе. спасибо, кстати, за Ваше преобразование кода, но оно вызывает дополнительные исключения.

Comment: а `p3(n)`  - что известно о данной функции? что она делает?

Comment: это число разбиений числа n на 3 слагаемых

Comment: т.е. задача - пользователь вводит несколько чисел, а алгоритм для каждого числа выдает кол-во разбиений на 3 слагаемых?

Comment: именно! чуть выше в ответе я приводил более конкретное определение задачи...

Comment: @vladionair, добавил в конце своего ответа код который кажется (насколько я понял задачу) является решением

Comment: весьма лаконичное решение! признателен Вам за него! +100500 в карму;)

Comment: @vladionair, на самом деле решение не очень оптимальное, если сделать `for j in range(i + 1, n + 1 - i):` то код будет работать побыстрее слегка - ведь не надо заведомо рассматривать `j` сумма которых с `i` даст значение больше `n`

Comment: еще раз спасибо за помощь и развернутый ответ!